# Can IWebBrowser2 store cookies in a user specified folder?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cookies, browser, iwebbrowser2

I am working on a small web browser on c++ using IWebBrowser2, the problem is that when I delete cookies on my browser, they get deleted for IE, and I dont want to interfere with IE cookies. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

IWebBrowser2 *is* Internet Explorer, so you're not really writing another browser. You're just writing a browser host that is re-hosting the Trident rendering engine. and associated plumbing. So unless I'm completely off base here (anyone?) the answer is a resounding "no."

-Oisin